# Rotate image left/right as we can do in gallery and save

Tags: android, image, rotation

I am trying to rotate image left/right as we can do in gallery and saving it, problem is I am losing the quality and when I open the gallery, the thumbnail of rotated image show original(not rotated) and when I open the image then I see original image (not rotated) and after a seconds gallery loads the rotated image.

Ideally how it should happen, you can check that in your gallery, try rotated an image, you can see even the thumbnail get rotated properly.

In short I want to rotate image left/right as we see in gallery.
Please do the needful.

I tried many solutions

What I have done is

When user clicks rotate left/right icon in my app I execute this code

```
private void writeRotatedBitmap(float angle) {

    try {

        File file = new File(sheetPaths.get(count));

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sheetPaths.get(count));

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        bmp =  Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);

        FileOutputStream out;
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        bmp = null;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: want ..click to rotate left and right ??

Comment: yea, i want click to rotate left/right that must be permanent change every where...